# force vim background to black

Tags: vim, color-scheme

Is there any way, in my vimrc, to override the background setting of my colorscheme and force it to black? I'm looking for something like

```
set colorscheme=wombat256
override_background(black)
```

so that whatever scheme I select, the background gets forced to black.

Comment: What if the foreground text in the theme is black as well?

Comment: then i'll get invisible text :) i mostly want this because there lots of themes that i like except for the grey/dark blue/otherwise off-black background, and it would be handy to not have to change them individually.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
 colorscheme wombat256
 highlight Normal guibg=black guifg=white
 set background=dark
```

Tweak to taste :)

@edit: after reading you later comment I suspect you'll find you need to override more related highlight (group) background colors. It'll be clearest which ones, by reading the existing color schemes

Comment: thanks :) that pointed me in the right direction. the actual command was highlight Normal ctermbg=None, thanks to a gnome terminal bug in which Black is not black [http://superuser.com/questions/142486/black-backgrounds-appear-grey-on-gnome-terminal]

Comment: I have to put `set background=dark` before the `highlight` override in order to make this work.

Answer (score 7):

This is what worked for me:

```
colorscheme wombat256
hi Normal ctermbg=16 guibg=#000000
hi LineNr ctermbg=16 guibg=#000000
```